# I can't see the view using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, methods

I have a problem with seeing a view.

Well, I went to url that will take me to the view and I added the link

```
  <a href="{{URL::to('/view_product/'.$v_published_product->product_id)}}">
       <p>{{$v_published_product ->product_name}}</p>
  </a>
```

then I went to the routing file and I added the route :

```
Route::get('/view_product/{product_id}', 'HomeController@product_details_by_id');
```

I went to the controller and I wrote the product_details_by_id method :

```
public function product_details_by_id($product_id) {
    $product_by_details=DB::table('tbl_products')
        ->join('tbl_category','tbl_products.category_id','=','tbl_category.category_name')
        ->join('tbl_manufacture','tbl_products.manufacture_id','=','tbl_manufacture.manufacture_name')
        ->select('tbl_products.*','tbl_category.category_name','tbl_manufacture.manufacture_name')
        ->where('tbl_products.product_id',$product_id)
        ->where('tbl_products.publication_status',1)
        ->limit(18)
        ->first();
    $manage_product_by_details=view('pages.product_details')
        ->with('product_by_details',$product_by_details);

       
    return view('layout')
         ->with('pages.product_details',$manage_product_by_details);
```

When I go the link /view-product/32 as an example: I found just the layout without the page pages.product_details.

Ps : I did not forget to put @extends('layout') @section('content') and @endsection.

#### edit 1 :

i tried to make the method simple:

```
public function product_details_by_id($product_id) {view('pages.test')}
```

test is a view i created in pages folder with "hello!!". Normally i have to see a white page with Hello!! but all I see is a white page.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you need to return the view: return view('pages.test');

Comment: Yes i forgot to return it. thank youu!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in the controller:

```
public function product_details_by_id($product_id) {
    $product_by_details=DB::table('tbl_products')
        ->join('tbl_category','tbl_products.category_id','=','tbl_category.category_name')
        ->join('tbl_manufacture','tbl_products.manufacture_id','=','tbl_manufacture.manufacture_name')
        ->select('tbl_products.*','tbl_category.category_name','tbl_manufacture.manufacture_name')
        ->where('tbl_products.product_id',$product_id)
        ->where('tbl_products.publication_status',1)
        ->limit(18)
        ->get();

    return view('pages.product_details')
         ->with('product_by_details',$product_by_details);
}
```

Comment: Also here i have changed the first() to get(), because you are using limit(18).first() will give you only one value.

Comment: Sorry for the late. and thank you for your comment. well i tried your code. i can now see the page but its just  an html code. any idea?

Comment: can you show me the view? 'pages' is your directory name and 'product_details.blade.php' is your view name right?

Comment: I think you may have missed the .blade in your page name 'product_details.blade.php'. Please check it.

Comment: this is it!! I forgot the "a" in blade. Thank you so much!! i really appreciate  it

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure that the pages folder is inside resources/views
2. and return view('pages.test');

Comment: Sorry for the late. oh yes i forgot to return view('pages.test'). now I can see Hello! but still the same problem with the original view